# How to create an editable textarea field in React JS with options for bold and italics which can parse/save embedded tags in the string

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tags, textarea

I need a way to display an editable textarea as part of a larger object. This textarea needs to be resizeable, be able to show both **bolded** and *italic* text, and also be able to parse values from strings that includes tags. For example, if passed,

<b>the question</b> <i>the answer</i>

It would display

**the question** *the answer*

The current code I have set up looks like the following:

```
    return (
        <textarea
            rows={props.rows}
            name={props.name}
            onChange={(e) => props.setValue(e.target.value)}
            value={props.value || ''}
            style={props.style}
            className={className}
        />
    )
```

This successfully creates an editable field which would display the above string as

<b>the question</b> <i>the answer</i>

...instead of properly bolding/italicizing it.

How can I create an object which meets these requirements? Either natively or with a library:

1. Editable field Display text
2. Allows user to bold/italicize text
3. Parse strings for bold/italics tags embedded in the string itself

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a WYSIWYG (What You See Is What You Get)/Rich Text Editor which utilizes the content editable property of a html element (generally a div). There are some libraries like

- [Slate](https://www.slatejs.org/)
- [Draft.js](https://draftjs.org/)
- [Prosemirror](https://prosemirror.net/)

[`Slate.js`](https://github.com/ianstormtaylor/slate/blob/main/site/examples/richtext.tsx) example (go to the link for full example):

```
import React, { useCallback, useMemo } from 'react'
import isHotkey from 'is-hotkey'
import { Editable, withReact, useSlate, Slate } from 'slate-react'
import {
  Editor,
  Transforms,
  createEditor,
  Descendant,
  Element as SlateElement,
} from 'slate'
import { withHistory } from 'slate-history'

const RichTextExample = () => {
  const renderElement = useCallback(props => <Element {...props} />, [])
  const renderLeaf = useCallback(props => <Leaf {...props} />, [])
  const editor = useMemo(() => withHistory(withReact(createEditor())), [])

  return (
    <Slate editor={editor} initialValue={initialValue}>
      <Editable
        renderElement={renderElement}
        renderLeaf={renderLeaf}
        placeholder="Enter some rich text…"
        spellCheck
        autoFocus
        onKeyDown={event => {
          for (const hotkey in HOTKEYS) {
            if (isHotkey(hotkey, event as any)) {
              event.preventDefault()
              const mark = HOTKEYS[hotkey]
              toggleMark(editor, mark)
            }
          }
        }}
      />
    </Slate>
  )
}
```

`Draft.js` example:

```
import {Editor, EditorState, RichUtils} from 'draft-js';

const MyEditor = () => {
  const [editorState, setEditorState] = React.useState(
    () => EditorState.createEmpty(),
  );

  const handleKeyCommand = (command, editorState) {
    const newState = RichUtils.handleKeyCommand(editorState, command);

    if (newState) {
      setEditorState(newState);
      return 'handled';
    }

    return 'not-handled';
  }

  return (
    <Editor
      editorState={editorState}
      handleKeyCommand={handleKeyCommand}
      onChange={setEditorState}
    />
  );
}
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/35566476)

Comment: @ray thanks, but can you please suggest some edits as to how to make the answer better?

Comment: You can include example usages of the libraries and explain how the libraries can address OP's question. If the URLs are left in the answer, if the linked webpage is broken then the answer becomes useless by itself